Buttons styling incorrectly on safari V15 and newer versions
On my website I have various buttons with a custom styling. However on safari V15 and up it apperently ignores the styling and switches to the default safari buttons. I also have a button for submitting a form, but this button doens't even display the text that is supposed to be on there. When you click on it and the form isn't filled out correct, it suddently does display the text.
Here is the styling for the buttons:


button {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: typewriter;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 150ms ease;
}
<button>Button</button>



I tried a quick google search but couldn't find anything related to this.

Your CSS is working fine for me (Safari IOS 16). Please create a runnable snippet which definitely shows the problem so we can test it.

I have a silly question....is your rendered html actually a <button ...> element?

So I found the problem. It did actually apply the css, however Safari made the font blue so I tought it was the default Safari button. Pretty silly mistake.
I added:
button{
  color: black;
  font-weight: normal;
}

This also fixed the problem of the text not appearing.
